# Android facebook sdk 4 post text to wall

Tags: android, facebook, text, facebook-wall

I want to share only text via facebook sdk. I researched more time but generally use **ShareLinkContent** class. Its working but i dont want to add link only post text to user wall via to **ShareButton**. How i can do?

Code:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentDescription(Html.fromHtml(shareText).toString())
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
        .build();

ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Success..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Cancel..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {}
});

shareButton.setFragment(this);
shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

**FacebookSDK: 4.11.0**

Comment: You can't. The message should be written by the user. Not you.

Comment: if user share my text in application why again write this?

Comment: Because Facebook Platform Policy say that is not allowed. So if you want people to be able to share you follow it

Comment: now no way to post wall only text? what can i do?

Comment: Users can post text that they write. They can not post text that you write

Comment: i dont understand. Sdk 3 i do this. For example user add poem to favorite list. after user share the poem in facebook with facebook sdk write this in share dialog window?

Comment: Of course not. Read the Platform Policy. Share a link to the poem

Comment: thank you for help

Comment: ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle(Html.fromHtml(shareText).toString())
                .setContentDescription(Html.fromHtml(shareText).toString())
         .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                .build();

When i use this i dont see shareText only show url... So im very confused..

Comment: We fetch the text from the URL. Use og-tags on the webpage

Comment: i think there is a problem. because when i click the link open developers.facebook.com/android. My shareText doesnt see when click or any.. Its too bad. Any way to user share poem on wall without link etc..?

Comment: No. Link is the only way

Comment: hmm its too bad :/

Comment: Why? If you share a link anyone can open it.

Comment: When i was use sdk 3 if user click to share button poem to directly posting user wall and notify it Success. Now sdk 4 open share dialog and input empty and have link when i click link open the developer.facebook.com/android

Comment: Doesn't matter which version you use. It is not allowed by the policy